# Passing serialized data from jquery mobile to PHP using $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to pass form data to a PHP script but I can't access the data in PHP. I have tried this:

```
$.post('http://127.0.0.1/tum_old/testi.php', $('form#login_form').serialize(), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

After checking on the data being passed through `$('form#login_form').serialize()` by

```
var param = $('form#login_form').serialize();
console.log(param);
```

I get:

```
username=ihfufh&passwordinput=dfygfyf
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo "$username";
?>
```

Gives me this error:

> Undefined index: username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialise and send your data with something like this:

**jQuery / AJAX**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        // give your form the method POST
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        // give your action attribute the value yourphpfile.php
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })

})
```

Then receive it in PHP like this:

```
<?php
   // assign your post value
   $inputvalues = $_POST;
   $username = $inputvalues['username'];
?>
```

Comment: does cordova support $.ajax because this application will later be built on cordova?

Comment: Yes it will work but you need to whitelist the domain first. In your config : `<access origin="http://domain" />`

Comment: $('#form') is this the form id?

Comment: Yes it is the form id.